# Save url containing special characters into mysql database using cursor

Tags: mysql, django

I am about to save this url below to my mysql database (innodb) using the cursor object:

http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/publications/download/367/l{o}{o}fjonasbisanimaximiliangollanchrisianheigoldgeorghoffmeisterbj{o}rnplahlchristianschl{u}terralfneyhermann--the2006{rwth}parliamentaryspeechestranscriptionsystem--2006.pdf

the query statement is

```
dbquery = "INSERT INTO maintable (url,state) VALUES (%s,%s)"
dbqueryvalue = (url,'0')

The cursor.execute(dbquery,dbqueryvalue)
```

error:

_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'url' at row 1

Other urls seem to be OK, but on this one cannot be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Column url can store shorder string as you try to insert (243 characters).
Other URLs are shorter.

To expand column use:

```
ALTER TABLE maintable
  MODIFY COLUMN url VARCHAR(250)
```

Comment: This is not the problem. The url field can store 255 characters as show in the results of "describe maintable". Actually, before inserting this URL to the table, URLs longer than 255 are already filtered out.